# Запуск в Python приложения через subprocess.Popen с правами администратора?

Tags: python, subprocess

Нужно запустить приложение перед выполнением основного кода, посоветовали использовать subprocess.Popen, но при запуске выдает ошибку "Отказано в доступе", я так понимаю, нужно запускать с правами администратора. Как это сделать?

Comment: Запустите сам питон с такими правами

Comment: правой кнопкой мыши на консоли python, bat-нику, powershell-скрипту или что у вас и выберите `Запуск от имени администратора`.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130763/4279)